# delete the same selected row when use confirm massage in primeNG

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

In my angular project and by using *primeNg* table I want to delete row after confirmation,
so every row has a delete button when click on it the confirmation message showing, but the problem when click on confirm button the last row in the table deleted, not the same row was selected.

This my **HTML** :

```
 <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="showConfirm()"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></button>

<p-toast position="center" key="c" (onClose)="onReject()" [modal]="true" [baseZIndex]="5000">
    <ng-template let-message pTemplate="message">
        <div style="text-align: center">
            <i class="pi pi-exclamation-triangle" style="font-size: 3em"></i>
            <h3>{{message.summary}}</h3>
            <p>{{message.detail}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-g ui-fluid">
            <div class="ui-g-6">
                <button type="button" pButton (click)="onConfirm(rowData.id)" label="yes" class="ui-button-success"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-g-6">
                <button type="button" pButton (click)="onReject()" label="No" class="ui-button-secondary"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</p-toast>
```

in **components.ts** i use this methods:

```
  showConfirm() { // to show confirm massage
    this.messageService.add({key: 'c', sticky: true, severity:'warn', summary:'!Delete confirm', detail:'Are you shur to dlelete this client '});
  }

 onConfirm(id:Clients) {
    this.Service.deleteClient(id).subscribe(res => {})

  onReject() {
    this.messageService.clear('c');
}
```

referance of primeNg:[https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/toast]

**Update**

when I try to put the parameter `rowData.id` in showConfirm method in **HTML** and in **components.ts** `showConfirm(id:Clients)` and use concatenation in massage detail showing the selected row,

*HTML*

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="showConfirm(rowData.id)"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></button>
```

*components.ts*

```
showConfirm(id:Clients) { // to show confirm massage
    this.messageService.add({key: 'c', sticky: true, severity:'warn', summary:'!Delete confirm', detail:'Are you shur to dlelete this client '+id});
  }
```

but i dont know how to pass the same parameter from `showConfirm(id:Clients)` to `onConfirm()` method.

Comment: The problem probably comes from from the "rowData.id" that your confirm button references to, are you sure this is linked in any way to the delete button of the specific row you're trying to delete ? Each delete buttons should probably pass the current row's id when they call "showConfirm()", so that your dialog knows which id is attempted to be deleted.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support, there is no problem in `rowData.id` could you check-update, please.

Comment: Maybe I have miss understanding, all I need when I click on delete button show confirm message and after click yes button will delete the same row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't know if I'm got it right. But the way I would do it would be:

1-decalre a variable like deleteCandidate.

2-update it on showConfirm method.

```
showConfirm(id:Clients) { // to show confirm massage
this.deleteCandidate=id;
    this.messageService.add({key: 'c', sticky: true, severity:'warn', summary:'!Delete confirm', detail:'Are you shur to dlelete this client '+id});
  }
```

3-pass it to onConfirm.

```
 onConfirm(id:Clients)<--this parameter is useless
 {
        this.Service.deleteClient(this.deleteCandidate).subscribe(res => {})
```

Comment: Thanks very much, you made me fill happy if you don't mind I have another query: I want to replace `id` in concatenation by name how can I do it?

Comment: @MohamedElkast, instead of (click)="onConfirm(rowData.id)" you can use (click)="onConfirm(rowData)" then in method body you can access all the properties of object. onConfirm(obj){obj.name for example

Comment: Really I appreciate your support, it's great for me thanks a lot for your cooperation

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way is to use 'Confirm Dialog' of primeng.
[Documentation of Primeng ConfirmDialog](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/confirmdialog)

Comment: You are right, Sounds good, "the confirm message" more Appropriate for me